# HAProxy HTTPS Redirect to different domain

Tags: ssl, haproxy

Currently I have a HAProxy configuration which redirects all HTTP traffic to HTTPS.

```
frontend http-in
    bind *:80

    redirect scheme https code 301
```

I then have various HTTPS domains configured, each redirecting to a standard path and using their own backends.

```
frontend https-in
    bind *:443 no-sslv3 ssl crt /usr/local/etc/haproxy/cruise.pem crt /usr/local/etc/haproxy/rose.pem crt /usr/local/etc/haproxy/mirren.pem
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
    rspadd Strict-Transport-Security:\ max-age=31536000;\ includeSubDomains

    acl host_cruise     ssl_fc_sni_reg -i tom.cruise.de
    acl host_rose       ssl_fc_sni_reg -i ruby.rose.com
    acl host_mirren     ssl_fc_sni_reg -i helen.mirren.com

    acl movietime_context path -m beg /movietime/
    redirect location https://tom.cruise.de/movietime/login      code 301 if host_cruise     !movietime_context
    redirect location https://ruby.rose.com/movietime/login      code 301 if host_rose       !movietime_context
    redirect location https://helen.mirren.com/movietime/login   code 301 if host_mirren     !movietime_context

    use_backend cruise     if host_cruise
    use_backend rose       if host_rose
    use_backend mirren     if host_mirren
```

I now need to add support for `tom.cruise.com` and `tom.cruise.at`. All requests for `tom.cruise.de` and `tom.cruise.at` need to redirect to `tom.cruise.com`.

Obviously I need a new SSL certificate for `tom.cruise.com` but do I need certs for the other two domains? Can I configure all HTTP and HTTPS requests from `tom.cruise.de` and `tom.cruise.at` to redirect to `tom.cruise.com` without having to configure SSL certs for the `at` and `de` domains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do anything with HTTPS including redirect you will need a certificate for each domain.

But you could just redirect HTTP from those other domains and only use HTTPS on the main domain.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That clears some stuff up for me. I has already been redirecting the HTTP requests to the .com domain. If there aren't other SSL certs available for the other domains, is this simple HTTP forwarding good enough in your opinion? Or is it essential to forward the HTTPS connections to?